# Push content to Squid

Tags: push, squid

Hello I have an httpd server where I upload a big file (around 1GB) and I have 4 Squid servers in 4 other machines. I wonder if I can some how, push this file to the Squid servers so when the client connects, Squid will not have to ask my httpd.

P.S. If you can suggest me any on other way, I would be grateful!

Comment: I found some information about the subject here: http://serverfault.com/questions/478734/prefetch-and-cache-http-requests-on-squid-or-any-proxy-server?newreg=35bd16ca42944d7eb695c7946622f084

Comment: The linked answer talks about warming the cache through HTTP requests. It sounds like the original question (as well as mine) is around warming the cache _without_ having to make any HTTP call to the backend. Curious if the original author ever found anything around this (for Squid, Varnish, or other)?

Comment: @AndyShinn I didn't. If I remember correctly, I made some scripts to probe the squid servers every time I was updating my large files.